# Compactness of a set : $A=\left\lbrace 2019,1010,\ldots,(n+2018)/n,\ldots \right\rbrace$ and $B=A \cup \left\lbrace 1 \right\rbrace$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

How can I show directly (that is, not using the compactness criterion in $\mathbb{R}$) that every open cover $G$ of $B$ admits a finite subcover?

I know that $A$ is not compact and I am aware that I would need a single example to prove it, any hint on how to find an open cover of $A$ that does not contain a finite subcover?

Comment: Any open set containing $1$ will contain all but a finite number of the elements of $A$. For the other part, construct a collection of open non overlapping intervals that contain the points. This is straightforward because the points are ordered.

Comment: @copper.hat is this an open cover of A that does not have a finite subcover (I believe it is)? ${G _x}$ is an open cover of A such that $G_x=N_(1/10)(x)$ (neighborhood of any point in A with radius 1/10)

Comment: I am not sure what notation you are using, but if you mean a ball of radium ${ 1\over 10}$ centred on $x$ then no. You need to adjust the size of the open set so it does not overlap with the others.

Comment: @copper.hat sorry I am not familiar with the notation used on this website. do you mean I need to find a smaller radius?

Answer (score 1):

If I take some open cover of $B$, there is some (at least one) open set $U_1$ which covers $1$. It must also cover some neighborhood of $1$ (since it is an open set). Since it covers some neighborhood of $1$, it will also cover almost any member of $A$ (you need to explain why in your proof - this is the main issue). Thanks to that fact, you only need finitely more open sets from the cover in order to cover $B$.

Comment: If you need a bigger hint let me know.

Comment: I may have found an open cover of A that does not have a finite subcover. Could you tell me if it is right? ${G _x}$ is an open cover of A such that $G_x=$N_1/10(x)$, for all x in A

Comment: Could your describe what you mean exactly? (I don't understand what is the cover)

Comment: I am so bad at this. My thought was to choose the set of all the neighborhoods with radius r (or 1/10 or any number) centered around each point in A

Comment: Alright, then I claim that there actually is a finite subcover of this cover. Again, there is some open set in the cover that covers 1 - it is of radius 1/10. There are only finitely many elements of B that are farther from 1 than of radius 1/10 (lets say there are n such elements), and so we can create our finite subcover from n+1 sets - the one that covers 1 and n open sets of radius 1/10 that cover the remaining (uncovered) members that are farther from 1 than 1/10. The proof is pretty much the same for any other open cover of B.

Answer (score 0):

We have $A=\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, note that $1<a_{n+1} < a_n$ and $a_n \downarrow 1$.

Let $b_n = {1 \over 2} (a_n+a_{n+1})$, the point half way between $a_n, a_{n+1}$.

Now take the open cover consisting of $(b_1,2020)$ and $(b_{n+1},b_n) $ for $n=1,...$.

Note that $A$ is not contained in any finite subcollection, hence $A$ is not compact.